# Web Scraping a Table Over Many Days

Tags: r, web-scraping, css-selectors, html-parsing, rvest

I've been webscraping using `XML::readHTMLTable`, and I'm now trying to learn how to scrape on a more granular level. My motivation came from trying to scrape a table on a website over multiple days that changes positions (e.g. yesterday it was 4th table on the page, today it was 2nd table on the page, etc.). I'm going to use a website which posts vegas-odds for various sports as an example, I will specifically be trying to pull NBA data.

```
URL1 = "http://www.scoresandodds.com/grid_20161123.html"
URL2 = "http://www.scoresandodds.com/grid_20161125.html"
```

You'll notice that the NBA table is the first table in `URL1` and it's the second table in `URL2`. Recognizing that NBA is the first table, here's how I would pull it for the first URL:

```
library(XML)

URL1 = "http://www.scoresandodds.com/grid_20161123.html"
exTable = readHTMLTable(URL1)[[1]] %>%
# Find first blank, since NBA is the first table #
  head(which(exTable[,1] == "")[1] - 1)
```

Then I would clean it up from there. I know that this is not the best way to do it, before even considering that I'd want to loop over many days, due to all the cleaning that needs to take place. It would be better to learn how to grab specific objects within a webpage table.

I've played around with `rvest` some and I know I can get nodes that look like "td.line" for Vegas lines, but I get lost trying to select the nodes for specific tables (`css = "#nba > div.sport"` or something?). I don't necessarily want the answer to this specific example, but learning how to do this example would allow me to apply the skills to many other cases. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on a good track here; you need a more apt CSS or XPath selector. Using rvest, you can grab both with the same code if your selector is good enough:

```r
library(rvest)

URL1 = "http://www.scoresandodds.com/grid_20161123.html"
URL2 = "http://www.scoresandodds.com/grid_20161125.html"

html1 <- URL1 %>% read_html()
df1 <- html1 %>% html_node('#nba ~ div table') %>% html_table()

html2 <- URL2 %>% read_html()
df2 <- html2 %>% html_node('#nba ~ div table') %>% html_table()

str(df1)
#> 'data.frame':    65 obs. of  7 variables:
#>  $ Team          : chr  "7:05 PM EST" "701 PHOENIX SUNS" "702 ORLANDO MAGIC" "PHO-F-T.J. Warren-? | TV: FS-Florida, DTV: 654" ...
#>  $ Open          : chr  "7:05 PM EST" "206.5" "-4.5" "PHO-F-T.J. Warren-? | TV: FS-Florida, DTV: 654" ...
#>  $ Line Movements: chr  "7:05 PM EST" "207.5 / 208 / 209.5" "-4 -15 / -4.5  / -4.5 -05" "PHO-F-T.J. Warren-? | TV: FS-Florida, DTV: 654" ...
#>  $ Current       : chr  "7:05 PM EST" "210" "-4" "PHO-F-T.J. Warren-? | TV: FS-Florida, DTV: 654" ...
#>  $ Moneyline     : chr  "7:05 PM EST" "+155" "-175" "PHO-F-T.J. Warren-? | TV: FS-Florida, DTV: 654" ...
#>  $ Halftime      : chr  "7:05 PM EST" "109" "-4" "PHO-F-T.J. Warren-? | TV: FS-Florida, DTV: 654" ...
#>  $ Scores        : chr  "7:05 PM EST" "92Under 210" "87final" "PHO-F-T.J. Warren-? | TV: FS-Florida, DTV: 654" ...

str(df2)
#> 'data.frame':    75 obs. of  7 variables:
#>  $ Team          : chr  "1:05 PM EST" "701 SAN ANTONIO SPURS" "702 BOSTON CELTICS" "TV: CSN-New England, FS-Southwest, DTV: 642, 676" ...
#>  $ Open          : chr  "1:05 PM EST" "-2.5" "203.5" "TV: CSN-New England, FS-Southwest, DTV: 642, 676" ...
#>  $ Line Movements: chr  "1:05 PM EST" "-3  / -3.5 -15 / -3.5" "199 / 200 / 201" "TV: CSN-New England, FS-Southwest, DTV: 642, 676" ...
#>  $ Current       : chr  "1:05 PM EST" "-3.5 -05" "201.5" "TV: CSN-New England, FS-Southwest, DTV: 642, 676" ...
#>  $ Moneyline     : chr  "1:05 PM EST" "-155" "+135" "TV: CSN-New England, FS-Southwest, DTV: 642, 676" ...
#>  $ Halftime      : chr  "1:05 PM EST" "-4.5" "106" "TV: CSN-New England, FS-Southwest, DTV: 642, 676" ...
#>  $ Scores        : chr  "1:05 PM EST" "109Over 201.5" "103final" "TV: CSN-New England, FS-Southwest, DTV: 642, 676" ...
```

In this case, the CSS selector

- looks for a node with an ID of `nba`, then
- looks for a `div` after that, then
- selects the `table` node inside of it.

You can write the same thing in XPath, if you like, which would let you use the XML package, if you really like. If you want to up your CSS selector skills, [the tutorial linked in `?rvest::html_node`](http://flukeout.github.io/) is fun and efficient.

If you want to scrape a lot of similar URLs at once, you can put them in a vector and iterate over it with `lapply`, or more conveniently `purrr::map_df`. Scrape responsibly; it's kind to put a `Sys.sleep` call in the anonymous function so as to behave more like a normal site visitor.

Comment: Hey there, sorry for the late reply but I wanted to let you know that I got my function working over multiple days with your help. On your note about scraping responsibly, I always will put a sys.Sleep at the beginning of every loop, but I was wondering if there's a standard "etiquette" for the amount of time. I have 2 seconds in right now, would ~10 be more appropriate?

Comment: The site doesn't have a `crawl-delay` listed in its robots.txt, but Bob Rudis has done a nice analysis of what's typical: https://rud.is/b/2017/07/28/analyzing-wait-delay-settings-in-common-crawl-robots-txt-data-with-r/ tl;dr: 5-10s is pretty normal.

Comment: sorry to bug you again, but I'm stuck on another (seemingly) easy problem. I'm now practicing on URL1 = "https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/nba/daily-fantasy-salary-changes?date=2017-11-25". The table ID = "stat-table", so I run `URL1 %>% read_html() %>% html_node("#stat-table") %>% html_table()`, but it only gives me the headers. It doesn't look like the tbody contains anything. Do you know why it doesn't pick up `tr.salary-row` or why the whole table doesn't fill in? All the info is in the "page source" but I don't know how to get it. Thanks!

Comment: That page forwards to the main NBA page for me (maybe it needs a login?), so I can't really tell. Usually that sort of thing happens because the data is loaded with JavaScript, though, which means you'd need to either figure out how the API gets it or use a scraper that can run the JavaScript like splashr or RSelenium.